# Two parameters are specified in the method named as CreateDog. So can someone tell me what happens by using two parameters like that?

Tags: c#, .net

```
 public IActionResult CreateDog(DogViewModel dogViewModel)
 {
   return View();
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`DogViewModel` is the type of parameter `dogViewModel`. So that's only one parameter, not two.

Comment: Thank you.. Can you explain this in detail

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods